# Issue with uppercase and lowercase using MySql Springdata and Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a database which contains an Assignment table. The table looks like this:

```
ID | CHARACTER_ASS | TYPE_ASS
```

Inside the character column letters and numbers are stored. Ie. 'A', 'a', "Aa". "AA", 1 etc...
Now when i execute the following query in my query console:

```
select * from assignment a where a.CHARACTER_ASS = 'A'
```

It will return the lowercase entry in my database and the uppercase entry as well. Now I've been looking for an answer to this question and someone told me that this might because I'm running on a Windows OS. I've looked this up and could only find that there could be a problem with naming table names with/without lowercase (?).

One of the other problems is that I'm using spring data. In spring data I don't have direct control of the query so I'm wondering if there is a specific fix for spring data.

I'd like to hear your answers regarding this issue :)

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My SHOW CREATE TABLE assignment:

```
CREATE TABLE `assignment` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CHARACTER_ASS` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `TYPE_ASS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EDIT2**

I changed my Assignment table Collation to: latin1_general_cs and I tried querying manually in the MySql query editor, but I still get A and a back as result.
Then i tried to adjust the collation of the table to the same value as I did with the table. 
Am i doing something wrong or should the adjustment work?

**EDIT3**

Ok I just fixxed it. Instead of using the latin1_general_cs I used utf8_bin. Seems that utf8 doesn't have a Case Sensitive Collation :) Thank you JB Nizet for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Here's the first result I get when googling for "mysql case-sensitive": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: I also found that but it wont help me cause of springdata. I have no clue to use COLLATE with springdata

Comment: Don't use collate. Configure the table to use a binary collation.

Comment: Could u post an example so I can up-vote you and accept your answer (if it works :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a case-sensitive collation when you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE assignment (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CHARACTER_ASS varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    TYPE_ASS int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8, COLLATE=latin1_general_cs
```

Note that the default collation can also be set globally, at the database level: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html

Comment: So the answer to this all is to use latin1_general_cs? Can I use this as a default setting for all my projects? or is there a downside to using this

Comment: When I run you code I get the following error:   Error Code: 1253. COLLATION 'latin1_general_cs' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8'

Comment: Choose the collation that suits you. But if you want String comparisons to be case sensitive, the collation must be a case-sensitive or binary one. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html, and don't hesitate to click on the links on the right side of the page. The show collation statement shows all the collations and their charset

Comment: You know a fix for my last comment?

Comment: The show collation statement shows all the collations and their charset. See dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: Hmm not sure if it's just me or that i'm implementing it the wrong way. I'll update my question with what I did.

Answer (score 0):

What is the character set and collation for that field?

could you execute SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;